# Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 in a pc with Windows 10. I have enabled the SQL Server Browser and Agent services both in SQL Server Configuration Tools and Windows Services.

I have restarted the server and even the computer itself, but when I open localhost:1433 in Chrome I only get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

Why? Is not possible to check if is up and running by accessing the ip:port combination on a browser??? I'm also trying to connect to it from a Node application with mssql and I can't.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Browser service introduced in SQL Server 2005, runs as a Windows service and it is an extension of SQL Server Resolution Protocol (SSRP) of SQL Server 2000. Like SSRP it plays an important role while working with more than one SQL Server instance installed on the same machine. The basic purpose of the SQL Server Browser service is to provide instance and port information to incoming connection requests.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Browser service listens on UDP port 1434, not TCP 1433.  Below is an example Powershell script that sends UDP query and displays the returned datagram.

```
# query SQL Server browser to test connectivity and get datagram
function QuerySqlBrowser($HostName)
{
    try
    {
        $udpClient = new-object Net.Sockets.UdpClient($HostName, 1434);
        $browserQueryMessage = new-object byte[] 2;
        $browserQueryMessage[0] = 2;
        $remoteEndPoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast, 0);
        $bytesSent = $udpClient.Send($browserQueryMessage, 2);
        $udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
        $browserResponse = $udpClient.Receive([ref]$remoteEndPoint);
        $payloadLength = $browserResponse.Length - 3;
        $browserResponseString = [System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII.GetString($browserResponse, 3, $payloadLength);
        Write-Host $browserResponseString;
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message;
    }

}

QuerySqlBrowser "YourServer";
```

Separately, you can use TELNET to verify TCP connectivity to the port the SQL Server instance is listening on (default 1433) or with this Powershell one-liner:

```
1433 | % { echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("YourServer",$_)) "server listening on TCP port $_" }
```